# Java adding a button

Tags: java, jbutton

So I tried to add a button to my game, but I can't understand, how to make the code work. Here's the code for my Launcher class (which has the button code and launches my whole game, imports and package not included):

```
public class Launcher extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game("Ninja Adventures", 720, 480);
        game.start();
        JButton button = new JButton("hello agin1");
        Game.add(button);
        button.addActionListener (new Action1());
    }

    static class Action1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     

            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Clicked");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(200,200);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("you clicked me");
        }
    }
}
```

Some extra code, that I think might help:

```
private void createDisplay(){
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: add the button to the Launcher, since that is your UI.

Comment: Please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We do not want to download your project to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem is that I barely understand my own code, 'cause I am really new to Java, and most of my code is pure copy-paste. And I'm not proud of that.

Answer (score 0):

As already said you need to add the JButton to the JFrame. Which in this case is in another method. So you can create the button in that method an add it like so: `frame.add(button);`

Or you pass the button to the method via the constructor (I recommend the first version).

Comment: It says, that I "cannot use this in a static context"

Comment: Oh, i see. Do you already have a frame displayed at the screen?

Comment: Yes. :/ I should really sit and read my code for "few" times, so I could give info that is necessary.

Comment: Could you paste the code where that frame is created to your question, as I can't download it to a mobile device?

Comment: So all You mean is that I need to move my code to another class? The one who has all of that JFrame code?

Comment: Exactly. But just the code involving the Button has to be moved.

Comment: If You're still there, uhm, how do I change the location of my button? What command line do I need to use? @Jeanma

Comment: Set the frames layout to null : `frame.setLayout(null);` then use `button.setBounds(xPos, yPos, width, height);` to set size and position of your button.

Comment: Sorry, was off my game for a while. Like FOR A WHILE. Will try out in a while.

Comment: Welp, no, it didn't work, but I think that's purely, 'cause of my poor java knowledge, and having no idea where to type that in, or apply it to my code